# Python Deepcopy and Manual Copy Give Different Result

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using deepcopy in my program. It works fine for the result. However, the usage of deepcopy make the performance of my program really slow. So, I try to do manual copy by creating the object itself. When I compare the performance, it gives better performance but the program result is different.

This is my code for deepcopy.

```
temp_location = deepcopy(self.locations)
```

And this is my code after replacing deepcopy with creating manual copy of the object.

```
temp_location = self.new_deepcopy(self.locations)

def new_deepcopy(self, locations):
    result = []
    for location in locations:
        result.append(Location(
           location.location_id,
           location.open_time,
           location.close_time,
           location.price,
           location.score,
           location.duration)
        )
    return result
```

`self.locations` is list of `Location` and `Location` is the object that I define like this.

```
class Location:
    def __init__(self, location_id, open_time, close_time, price, score, duration):
        self.location_id = location_id
        self.open_time = open_time
        self.close_time = close_time
        self.price = price
        self.score = score
        self.duration = duration
        self.waiting_time = 0
        self.visit_time = 0
        self.leave_time = 0
```

How to make the exact copy with different reference without using deepcopy? Why the `new_copy` that I create give the different result?

Comment: Can you explain how the result is different?

Comment: What is the difference in behavior you're seeing?

Comment: How are the results different?  If you want the behavior of `deepcopy`, why not just *use* `deepcopy`?

Comment: @ScottHunter because I want to improve the performance of my program.

Comment: "sometimes it is not equal": In what way(s)?

Answer (score 1):

I think your 'new_deepcopy' is apparently not deep copying your variables. To my understanding of python (please correct me if i am mistaken) every variable in Python is a pointer to a memory location. So what your new_deepcopy is probably doing is just passing on this pointers to an object and not the actual values. And this is why your code seems to be faster but returns wrong results. If you want to improve the performance of your code you might want to consider the use of cython

Comment: According to this explanation if I do `a=1;b=a;a=2` then `b` should be `2`. This is not true. The difference is how mutable and immutable objects are treated.

Comment: As I mentioned above I'm not completely certain about how python handles those things. But to my understanding the code provided creates a new object that contains references to the old values. Check the official docs [https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/copy.html]

Comment: [Facts and myths about Python names and values](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

Comment: @Matthias you are right about your example. But try the following: **a=[1,2,3,4], b=a, a.append(5), b >> [1,2,3,4,5]**

Comment: That's the mentioned difference between mutable and unmutable objects. In this question we don't know the type of the objects attributes, so we're just guessing what happens.